# How to resize images in multi-column Layout?

Tags: css

i'm trying to make a Masonry page working with multi-columns, but my images looks huge, not like they should.

how can i resize and make them smaller?

i've tried to add a padding to the .container, it worked in a way, but the moment you

change the screen size it's a disaster, all becomes very tiny.

Thanks!

```
<div class="titolo">
<h1>Esercitazione</h1>
<h2>Riprodurre un layout</h2>
</div>


<div class="super">
    <div class="container">
        <img src="1.jpeg">
        <img src="2.jpeg">
        <img src="3.jpeg">
        <img src="4.jpeg">
        <img src="5.jpeg">
        <img src="6.jpeg">
        <img src="7.jpeg">
        <img src="8.jpeg">
        <img src="9.jpeg">
        <img src="10.jpeg">
      
        
        </div>
</div>
```

```
[![enter image description here][1]][1]
.titolo {
    padding: 30px;
}

h1 {
   text-align: center;
   font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}
h2 {
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
    font-style: italic;
}

/* immagini */


.container {
    
    column-count: 3;
    column-gap: 20px;
    margin:70px auto;
    
    
    
}

img {
    
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
    
    
}





@media (max-width: 800px) {
    .container {
        column-count: 2;
       
    }
}

@media (max-width: 400px) {
    .container {
        column-count: 1;
    }
}


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Q07p.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

Your images are currently set to take up the full width of your container. So the width of your images are going to adjust in relation to the width of the page and the number of containers you're choosing to display at that width. I made a version and added some common breakpoints, take a look and let me know if that's what you're looking to do.

```css
.titolo {
    padding: 30px;
}

h1 {
   text-align: center;
   font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}
h2 {
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
    font-style: italic;
}

/* immagini */


.container {
    column-count: 4;
    column-gap: 20px;
    margin:70px auto;      
}

img {
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
}

@media (max-width: 1200px) {
    .container {
        column-count: 3;
       
    }
}

@media (max-width: 992px) {
    .container {
        column-count: 2;
       
    }
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
    .container {
        column-count: 1;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="titolo">
<h1>Esercitazione</h1>
<h2>Riprodurre un layout</h2>
</div>

<div class="super">
    <div class="container">
        <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Q07p.jpg">
        <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Q07p.jpg">
        <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Q07p.jpg">
        <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Q07p.jpg">
        <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Q07p.jpg">
        <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Q07p.jpg">
        <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Q07p.jpg">
        <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Q07p.jpg">
        <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Q07p.jpg">
        <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Q07p.jpg">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: they still look very huge unfortunately; i've tried to add a width: 70vw to the container and it seems to be a little better, but i'm not sure its the correct way to do it ? i'm adding another question, what if a want them to look all the same in size? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

in my opinion to resize the image by wrapping it with a div element class `.container-img` which the style remains the same as before, but the img element must be styled `width: 80%; margin: 0 auto;`

```
[![enter image description here][1]][1]
.titolo {
  padding: 30px;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
}
h2 {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
  font-style: italic;
}

/* immagini */

.container {
  column-count: 3;
  column-gap: 20px;
  margin: 70px auto;
}

.container-img {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}
.container-img img {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

@media (max-width: 800px) {
  .container {
    column-count: 2;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 400px) {
  .container {
    column-count: 1;
  }
}

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Q07p.jpg
```

```
<body>
    <div class="titolo">
      <h1>Esercitazione</h1>
      <h2>Riprodurre un layout</h2>
    </div>

    <div class="super">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="container-img">
          <img src="1.jpeg" />
        </div>
        <div class="container-img">
          <img src="2.jpeg" />
        </div>
        <div class="container-img">
          <img src="3.jpeg" />
        </div>
        <div class="container-img">
          <img src="4.jpeg" />
        </div>
        <div class="container-img">
          <img src="5.jpeg" />
        </div>
        <div class="container-img">
          <img src="6.jpeg" />
        </div>
        <div class="container-img">
          <img src="7.jpeg" />
        </div>
        <div class="container-img">
          <img src="8.jpeg" />
        </div>
        <div class="container-img">
          <img src="9.jpeg" />
        </div>
        <div class="container-img">
          <img src="10.jpeg" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
```

to resize image change style `width :`  in class `.container-img img`